# Проблемы с постановкой боевого сервера Django+nginx+gunicorn

Tags: python, django

Имею готовый мини-магазин на Django, для теста регистрировал акк на http://www.vps.me получил ssh-доступ - ввел в терминале команду - потом пароль, всё отлично, далее, следуя гайду (http://djbook.ru/examples/62/), установил **gunicorn**, ввел gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application --bind 31.220.50.107:8000 и получил **ошибку**:

> [2015-02-24 01:25:11 +0000] [8721]
> [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.2.1
>     [2015-02-24 01:25:11 +0000] [8721] [ERROR] Invalid address:
> ('31.220.50.107', 8000)

Почему адрес не валиден, что я мог упустить? Более ясного гайда я не нашел, может, подкинет кто парочку советов?

Comment: Даже дучше наверное биндить на 0.0.0.0:8000 чтобы было доступно не только с локальной машины

Answer (score 1):

Если nginx будет на этом же сервере то забиндь на localhost: `gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application --bind 127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: Дело в том, что я уже настраивал nginx+qunicorn+Django на localhost(e), всё отлично, но как дело дошло на перенос сервера с поддержкой vps...